# why are widgets placed on the TabItem invisible when using ScrolledComposite SWT?

Tags: java, swt, scrollbar

Here is my code which actually does all the GUI work for Domain(right side contained in the picture attached).In this function What i am doing is I am creating a composite "test" on the "newTabFolder".Then i am creating ScrolledComposite "sc" on it and then Creating a composite "compositeInTab" on it and after placing all the widgets on "compositeInTab" I am creating a TabItem for placing the composite "test" on it.

```
public DomainUI(Composite composite, TabFolder newTabFolder, boolean comingFromSelf)
{
    Composite test = new Composite(newTabFolder,SWT.NONE);
    test.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(test, SWT.V_SCROLL|SWT.H_SCROLL);
    final Composite compositeInTab = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);
    sc.setExpandHorizontal(true); 
    sc.setExpandVertical(true);
    sc.setMinHeight(compositeInTab.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT).y);
    sc.setMinWidth(compositeInTab.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT).x);
    sc.setContent(compositeInTab);
    compositeInTab.setLayout(null);
    sc.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);

    /*HERE I AM CREATING LABELS AND TEXT FIELDS AND SETTING THEIR BOUNDS*/
    systemCodeLabel = new Label(compositeInTab, 0);
    systemCodeText = new Text(compositeInTab, SWT.BORDER);
    systemCodeLabel.setText("System Code");
    systemCodeLabel.setBounds(350, 60, 100, 15);
    systemCodeText.setBounds(480, 60, 150, 17);
    // CREATION OF LABELS AND TEXTFIELDS ENDED

    // CREATION OF TABLE STARTS
    myTable = new CreateTable(compositeInTab, 1);
    myTable.setBounds(50, 230, 0, 0);
    myTable.table.setSize(myTable.table.computeSize(570, 250));

    //here i filled data in table

    for(int i=0; i<myTable.table.getColumnCount(); i++)
    {
        myTable.table.getColumn(i).pack();
     myTable.table.getColumn(i).setWidth(myTable.table.getColumn(i).getWidth()+10);
    }

    TabItem tabItem1 = new TabItem(newTabFolder, SWT.NONE);
    tabItem1.setText("Domain");
    tabItem1.setControl(test);
    newTabFolder.setBounds(0, 0, 480, 300);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a matter of layouts. I fiddled around a little bit and managed to get this working:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    ScrolledComposite scrollComp = new ScrolledComposite(shell, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    Composite innerComp = new Composite(scrollComp, SWT.NONE);
    innerComp.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, true));

    for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        new Button(innerComp, SWT.PUSH).setText("Button");

    scrollComp.setMinHeight(innerComp.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT).y);
    scrollComp.setMinWidth(innerComp.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT).x);
    scrollComp.setContent(innerComp);
    scrollComp.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    scrollComp.setExpandVertical(true);
    scrollComp.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    shell.setSize(200, 200);

    while(!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if(!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
}
```

It will show the scrollbars. However, if I change the layout of the shell to a `GridLayout`, it will not work. Maybe your "combination" of layouts seems to be the problem...

Comment: My code worked when i set the layout of test to FillLayout(). :)

Comment: @MubashirKamran That's great. Have fun with it :)

Comment: But can you please tell me about two issues still coming? First is that scroll bars are showing now but they are not scrollable for showing the other data and second is that when i increase the newTabFolder bounds it goes out of screen then all the widgets and scroll bars also go out of screen.How to manage these?

Comment: @MubashirKamran I don't really understand your problem. Can you provide an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) and maybe a screenshot?

Comment: Thanks for your time.I was just misunderstanding and making wrong use of scrolledcomposite.setMinSize(), scrolledcomposite.setMinWidth() and scrolledcomposite.setMinHeight() methods.Now i have fully functional scroll bars on my composite. :)

Comment: @MubashirKamran Great. It's always good if you can figure it out on your own.